# Send via Automation studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

Does Automation Studio allows users to define the parameters for a send. I believe in Journey builder we can do so.

Comment: Are you referring to the Send Email Activity in Journey Builder versus the Send Email Activity in Automation Studio? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, Eliot. This question is specific to Automation studio, I want to know that whether we can define the parameters for a send while using Automation Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email configuration options in the Send Email Activity in Journey Builder and Automation Studio are fairly similar. With both Activities you can:

1. Define CAN-SPAM classification
2. Override Send Profile
3. Override Delivery Profile
4. Exclude subscribers
5. Enable link tracking

The only main difference appears to be that in Journey Builder, the Send Email Activity (which is essentially a Triggered Send) also lets you set the priority of the email. However note that 'High' priority emails* are charged at a different rate (the number of Super Messages is higher than sending a standard email).

*Note: this 'High' priority option only appears if it's enabled on your account